# Including an jar file in a jar

Tags: java, datasource, c3p0

I have a Java protect with the [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) JAR. Compiling my project in eclipse works. No errors or something. But when i try to run my application it says the  following:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources`

Do i need to give the jar file the other jarfile from c3p0? Or could i link them when launging the application?

Comment: Are you trying to run it from within eclipse, or as an independent jar application?

Comment: @Vulcan No, i dont run it within eclipse. I have to export it as a JAR file for a server. My java code is a plugin for a java based message server.

Comment: This question is ultimately about easy deployment/installation, right?  I think you are better off looking to an installer than packaging all the app. resources in a single Jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:  I've understood your problem to be when running *outside* Eclipse.

The standard Java classloader responsible for loading your classes does not understand jar-files inside jar-files, so you need to do something else:

- You can merge all classes from all the jar-files you use into a single jar file.  (**recommended for you at this point, not general recomendation**)
- You can put jar-files inside the single jar-files and use a special classloader which understands this.
- You can put the referenced jars "next" to the single jar file containing your class files, and have the runnable jar include the necessary MANIFEST.MF voodo needed to refer to them.

The `File->Export->Runnable jar` option in Eclipse can do all three based on what you choose.  Pick the one best suited to how you will get the classes to the final users.

Personally I like the "jars next to the generated jar" as it is the closest to what is supported out of the box by Java, while keeping the original jar files.  The simplest is most likely to merge all classes, but when you get more advanced you will find that it has some disadvantages - at this point you will most likely not encounter them.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I dont use a runnable jar, but a Jar file. Its a plugin for other java software.

Comment: @KevinvanderBurgt I do not understand what "plugin for other java software" means.  A very good guess is that you've not packaged your plugin correctly regarding dependencies.

Comment: I use "File -> Export -> JAR file". And i dont have the option "Extract/Package required libraries into generated JAR".

Comment: @KevinvanderBurgt if you are using a reasonably modern version of Eclipse there should be _both_ "Export -> Jar file" _AND_ "Export -> Runnable Jar file".

Comment: I use the newest version. But when i click Runnable Jar file i cant export it.

Comment: Selected a launch configuration yet?

Answer (score 0):

Add C3P0 as external jar in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not added  c3p0 in the classpath when you run the sample.

However you could use maven and m2e plugin for eclipse and add the following

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

beside the other dependencies you have.

after mvn eclipse: eclipse and you will have your project with a correct classpath.

Comment: I have installed "Maven Integratio for Eclipse" and restarted Eclipse. Where can i put that text <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
 </dependency> ?